# Извлечь содержимое тега с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть динамическая ссылка

```
<a href="http адрес динамический" target="_blank">динамическое содержимое</a>
```

Надо что бы оставалось только 'динамическое содержимое'
делаю

```
$html_links = preg_replace('"\b(https?://\S+)"', '', $text);
```

остается

```
 <a href=" target="_blank">динамическое содержимое</a>
```

Помогите победить регексп, ничего не понимаю в нем.

Comment: Нужно извелечь контент тега <a></a> ?

Comment: ссылка внутри мне не нужна, вот контент, да нужен. просто что бы осталось 'динамическое содержимое'

Comment: Если у вас есть в вашей строке только один тег можно сделать много проще : `echo strip_tags("<a href='link' target='_blank'>динамическое содержимое</a>");`

Comment: Используйте [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php): [`$content = strip_tags($s);`](https://ideone.com/ayuvkl)

Answer (score 2):

```
$html_links = preg_replace('#<(/?)a\b.*?>#', '<$1span>', $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для захвата текста между тэгами `<a></a>` используйте группу `(.+)`.  Для замены всей строки на текст *первой группы* используйте `$1` в параметре-замены.

```
$text = '<a href="http адрес динамический" target="_blank">динамическое содержимое</a>';
$txt = preg_replace("/<a.+>(.+)<\/a>/", "$1", $text);
```

в результате переменная `$txt` будет иметь значение `динамическое содержимое`.

В целом такого же  результата вы добьетесь, используя функцию [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php):

```
$txt = strip_tags($text, "a")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = '<a href="http адрес динамический" target="_blank">динамическое содержимое</a>';

preg_match_all('/<a href.*">(.*)<\/a>/', $text, $html_links);

print_r($html_links);
```

Comment: вы проверили код?

Comment: сейчас работает :))