# PHP взять текст выбранного option у select

Tags: php, sql

```
<select>
   <option>Москва</option>
   <option>Казань</option>
</select>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/624492/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: `<option value="Москва">Москва</option>`

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы Вам получить значение через `php`, Вам в первую очередь необходимо сделать форму для отправки. 
Так же, чтобы не перебирать все полученные данные (когда их будет много) необходимо присвоить имя этому полю `select`, чтобы в дальнейшем к нему обращаться. 
Пример:

```php
<form method="post">
    <select name="select">
        <option>Москва</option>
        <option>Казань</option>
    </select>
    <button formmethod="post">Тык</button>
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST['select'])){
    $value = $_POST['select'];
}
print_r($value);
```